# Drawing shapes on images in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, shapes

I am trying to draw shapes on images in my flutter app(rectangles to be specific) for a classification problem. These shapes are drawn depending on some coordinates(width and height pixels). Cropping the image given these coordinates works for me too but I prefer the drawing thing. Is there any package that can do any of these for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `Stack`, with the bottom widget being the `Image` and any widgets above being `Containers` with `width`, `height` and `decoration`. You can align these containers using `Align` or `Positioned`.